# Extract tokens from the string C# regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I got string which needs to be separated by pipe |.

The numeric tokens can be defined without wrapping in anything like 20 and 50 in the example below or could be defined in [] or {}.

The string token will be either wrapped in [] or {} and can have any special characters including | separator within the token. They cannot have [] or {} within the token string.

[Name1]|20|[Nam|2]|{Na;me,3}|50|[Na|me!@#$%^&*()Finish]|[25]|{67}

Need to extract above string to following tokens:

Name1

20

Name|2

Na;me,3

50

Na|me!@#$%^&*()Finish

25

67

How can we do that in C#? Is regular expressions best way to go about it?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract them with

```
\[(?<r>[^][]*)]|\{(?<r>[^{}]*)}|(?<r>[^|]+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%28%3F%3Cr%3E%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%29%5D%7C%5C%7B%28%3F%3Cr%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%29%7D%7C%28%3F%3Cr%3E%5B%5E%7C%5D%2B%29&i=%5BName1%5D%7C20%7C%5BNam%7C2%5D%7C%7BNa%3Bme%2C3%7D%7C50%7C%5BNa%7Cme!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29Finish%5D%7C%5B25%5D%7C%7B67%7D). *Details*:

- `\[(?<r>[^][]*)]` - `[`, then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` captured into Group "r", and then a `]` char
- `|` - or
- `\{(?<r>[^{}]*)}` - `{`, then any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` captured into Group "r", and then a `}` char
- `|` - or
- `(?<r>[^|]+)` - any one or more chars other than a `|` char captured in Group "r".

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/T9KoqW):

```cs
var text = "[Name1]|20|[Nam|2]|{Na;me,3}|50|[Na|me!@#$%^&*()Finish]|[25]|{67}";
var pattern = @"\[(?<r>[^][]*)]|\{(?<r>[^{}]*)}|(?<r>[^|]+)";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["r"].Value);
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
Name1
20
Nam|2
Na;me,3
50
Na|me!@#$%^&*()Finish
25
67
```